# Extracting specific column from a text file in Java

Tags: java

I need to write a piece of software that is extracting integers from one of the columns in a text file and create an average. I've managed to extract first a number from a first line, but whenever I try to do it on more than one line it is creating an endless loop with first integer.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(new File("policy.txt"));
String line = lineScanner.nextLine();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
System.out.println(ints.get(10));
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you trying to do it for multiple lines? Because this code only runs it for 1 line

Comment: And where is the "specific column" part? That reads all numbers of the line.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I know it does. This is the code that actually works but its for only one line where I have to get integer on the same position from every line in the file

Comment: @Tom it reads all the numbers in the line but it only displays the one I want. All the numbers I need are on the same position in line.

Comment: each line has columns separated by some character?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(new File("policy.txt"));
 List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
 // read lines
 while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
     String line = lineScanner.nextLine();
     Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
     while (m.find()) {
         ints.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
     }
 }
 lineScanner.close();
 System.out.println(ints.toString());
```

Comment: You can improve performance by only compiling the pattern once. Write now, you’re compiling for each line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

What is the desired behavior?

With `column = 3` and this input:

```
1 2 34 5 6 7 8
1 2 5 6 7 8
1 2 45 6 7 8
1 2
1 2 56 6 7 8
```

This:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
List<Integer> ints = Files.lines(Paths.get("policy.txt"))
            .map(p::matcher)
            .map(m -> m.find(column) ? Integer.parseInt(m.group()) : null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(ints);
```

Prints: `[34, 5, 45, null, 56]`

And this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
List<Integer> ints = Files.lines(Paths.get("policy.txt"))
            .map(p::matcher)
            .filter(m -> m.find(column))
            .map(Matcher::group)
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(ints);
```

Prints: `[34, 5, 45, 56]`